# Is there a way to store the result of a while loop (using the random module) inside a new variable - to be reused?

Tags: python, random

I want to grab the 5 random results from **this function** (will be five key-value pairs from a dictionary), and re-use them. Is there any way to do that?

```
def display_cards():
  i = 1
  while i < 6:
    print("")
    time.sleep(3)
    random_number = random.randint(0, len(flashcards))
    CARDNAME = "flash_" + str(random_number) 
    print(flashcards[CARDNAME])
    i += 1
display_cards()
```

An example result might be this (just to give an idea):

```
{'ingenjör (n)': 'Engineer'}

{'lärare (n)': 'Teacher'}

{'programmerare (n)': 'Programmer'}

{'försäljare (n)': 'Salesman'}

{'snickare (n)': 'Carpenter'}
```

These five results will be different each time the code is run (from a total of 100). The challenge is to grab and keep that random result and store it somehow in a variable, to re-use that combination of key-value pairs. Is it possible?

Here I will show the first few "flashcards" (nested dictionaries in a dictionary), to give an idea of how they are formatted:

```
flashcards = {"flash_0" : {"vecka (n)": "week"},
              "flash_1" : {"år (n)": "year"},
              "flash_2" : {"idag (adv)": "today"},
              "flash_3" : {"imorgon (adv)": "tomorrow"},
              "flash_4" : {"igår (adv)": "yesterday"},
              "flash_5" : {"kalender (n)": "calendar"},
```

Comment: Do some reading on Python functions. The thing you are looking for is the `return` statement.  It allows you to return values from a function. You also need to use a list or a dictionary to collect the values in your while loop (which would be better as a for loop).

Comment: My flashcards are nested dictionaries stored in a dictionary named "flashcards." I didn't post the whole thing because there is 100 of them, and it would take up a lot of space. I didn't think that would be necessary to understand the problem, but I can definitely post that as well.

Comment: You could copy paste just the first few

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the return statement, and that was my first thought for how to get this to work, actually. However, after reading about it to try and find the answer, and some experimenting, it did not seem like using the return statement to do this was possible. But I guess, based on your comment, I must have missed something. Thank you for the tip. I will revisit the possibility of using the return statement here, although I still do not see/know how I can store this in a variable. Yes, putting it in a list or dictionary would be good.

Comment: @garagnoth I edited it now to show this. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your question, but the `random.sample` function can probably do what you want in one step, rather than with a loop picking values one at a time.

Comment: @Bill I appreciate the tips and am gonna try and implement this! I thought I had already exhausted the option of using the return statement to do this, but I am trying it again! I will let you know if I solve it! :)

Comment: @Blckknght  Thank you, yes you are right - but I have written it like this because I need it to specifically show each key-value pair ("flashcard") one at a time with a few seconds pause before the next one is printed out.

Comment: I'd suggest that it would be easier to pick the random flashcards up front with `random.sample` and then loop over them doing the printing and pausing as needed later. Hmm, maybe I should just answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code if you separate out the logic that choose the random flashcards from the loop that presents them to the user. The former can be really easy using `random.sample`!

```
import random

flashcards = {"flash_0" : {"vecka (n)": "week"},
              "flash_1" : {"år (n)": "year"},
              "flash_2" : {"idag (adv)": "today"},
              "flash_3" : {"imorgon (adv)": "tomorrow"},
              "flash_4" : {"igår (adv)": "yesterday"},
              "flash_5" : {"kalender (n)": "calendar"},
             }

sample = random.sample(flashcards.values(), 5) # pick 5 random values without repeating

for value in sample:  # loop over the values in the sample
    print()
    time.sleep(3)
    print(value)
```

You can then reuse the same `sample` for other code if you want.

As a final note, the `flashcards` dictionary would problable be better as a list, since the keys are not very meaningful (just a fixed string followed by an integer, where a list would just be indexed by the integer directly). Similarly, the values might be better as 2-tuples, rather than as one-element dictionaries. Dictionaries are great, but they're not ideal everywhere!

Comment: This was very helpful, as well. Thank you for showing me a different way to format my code, and still get it to do what I need it to do.

I will reconsider the dictionary issue. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

IUUC.

One way to do this is to store the result in a list of dictionary.

Assuming input:

```
flashcards = {
  "flash_0" : {"vecka (n)": "week"}, 
  "flash_1" : {"år (n)": "year"}, 
  "flash_2" : {"idag (adv)": "today"}, 
  "flash_3" : {"imorgon (adv)": "tomorrow"}, 
  "flash_4" : {"igår (adv)": "yesterday"}, 
  "flash_5" : {"kalender (n)": "calendar"}
}
```

The function, I've revised your function a bit as there are few unnecessary lines and unused variable `i`:

```
def display_cards():
  arr = []
  for _ in range(1, 6):
    random_number = random.randint(0, len(flashcards) - 1)
    CARDNAME = "flash_" + str(random_number)
    arr.append(flashcards[CARDNAME])
  return arr
```

Now, we can run the function and store the result on a variable. For example `abc`:

```
abc = display_cards()
```

Output:

```
[{'igår (adv)': 'yesterday'},
 {'vecka (n)': 'week'},
 {'år (n)': 'year'},
 {'idag (adv)': 'today'},
 {'igår (adv)': 'yesterday'}]
```

A more flexible approach, if the number of cards to draw can change in the future is to pass number of cards to draw in the function parameter. Something like the following:

```
def display_cards(number_of_cards_to_generate):
  arr = []
  for _ in range(number_of_cards_to_generate):
    random_number = random.randint(0, len(flashcards) - 1)
    CARDNAME = "flash_" + str(random_number)
    arr.append(flashcards[CARDNAME])
  return arr
```

Then, you can call the function as following:

```
cards = display_cards(5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this did give me some insight to help me continue to learn more, however I must say that the variable i is not unused. I do need that for the loop to work.
Also, the lines `print("")
    time.sleep(3)`  Add a necessary empty line between the cards that are printed out, as well as a 3-second pause (using the time module).

Comment: By unused, I mean you're not using it elsewhere other than for the loop. In which case, you can just use `_` (underscore). The `_` is a throwaway variable where its value is not really important. Also, by doing this, you don't have to declare `i = 0` at the beginning and then later on increment i. Noted on displaying the result line by line. You can definetely insert it back. Or, better, have it on separate function so that it'll be easier to manage in the future.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying. That is very interesting. I still have so much to learn! I'm brand new at this, and I really appreciate the pointers given. :D

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is to grab and keep that random result and store it somehow in a variable, to re-use that combination of key-value pairs. Is it possible?

yes just keep a variable outside of the scope of your function.

```
#keep a list of draws
card_sets = []

def display_cards():
  i = 1
  while i < 6:
    print("")
    time.sleep(3)
    random_number = random.randint(0, len(flashcards))
    CARDNAME = "flash_" + str(random_number) 
    print(flashcards[CARDNAME])
    #add it to the global list of cards 
    card_sets.append(flashcards[CARDNAME])
    i += 1
display_cards()
#now can access all the card draws in card_sets
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, that is perfect! Keep a variable outside of the scope of my function, and then use append just after the print statement in the function, to add to the empty list! This was perfect!  Wow, thank you, that makes so much sense! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way.. I decided to separate the selection of the cards from the display of selected cards.. because maybe it would make more sense later on to have these be separate functions...  But you could combine the loops if you like.  The important thing is to keep a list of what you selected so that you can refer to it later...

```
import random
import time

flashcards = {
    "flash_0" : {"vecka (n)": "week"},
    "flash_1" : {"år (n)": "year"},
    "flash_2" : {"idag (adv)": "today"},
    "flash_3" : {"imorgon (adv)": "tomorrow"},
    "flash_4" : {"igår (adv)": "yesterday"},
    "flash_5" : {"kalender (n)": "calendar"},
}

def display_cards():

    # I separated the selection of the cards to be displayed from the actual display of the
    # card for greater flexibility.  First, select a list of 5 cards at random...
    displayed_list = []
    while len(displayed_list) < 5:
        displayed_list.append(flashcards["flash_%s" % random.randint(0, len(flashcards)-1)])

    # Now, display the list of cards, slowly.
    for card in displayed_list:
        print("")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(card)

    # return the list so we can refer to it later
    return displayed_list

# call our function and get the returned list of cards...
cards_that_were_displayed = display_cards()
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it is a really interesting answer as well and I will consider this way also. Thank you for the help! I am brand new to python. :)